# Object error displaying a list from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

In the controller I populate the ViewBag with Types (TypeID, Name)

```
ViewBag.Types = types.ToList();
```

then in the view

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Types)
    {
       @item.Name
}
```

This errors with:
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: Can you please post the exact definition of your `types` variable?

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag ,ViewData or such dynamic Magic items are **evil** because they will never tell you whether your view is failing due to a misspelling error, while using a strongly-typed model you will get a compile-time error when there is a problem. And also you get Intellisense support too.

Why not use **strongly typed** approach ?

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  return View(types.ToList());
}
```

And make your View strongly typed to the object/objects

```
@model IList<Types>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: In this case, I need to use the ViewBag

Comment: Are you expecting the ViewBag to work in the same view as of the action you are setting it ? What is the reason behind not using ViewModel ?

Comment: Yes thats right. Its complicated! just need to be able to read a list from the ViewBag

Comment: Why do you say it is complicated ?Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose your types is a list of `foo`.
Pass your `ViewBag.Types` just the way you did and in the view do this :

```
@{
    var TypeList= (List<foo>)ViewBag.Types;
}
```

and then just do:

```
@foreach (var item in TypeList)
    {
       @item.Name
    }
```

Note:You might need to write the full path to your `foo` entity

Comment: Thats results in: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`2[System.Int32,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Please write the definition for types (from your controller).

Comment: var types = (from mt in db.MTypes
                         select new { mt.MTypeID, mt.Name });

Comment: so basically you want to show the Id and the name of all the entities within your db.MTypes . Correct ?

Comment: sorry mate ... gotta go . Hope you will get help from someone else .Have a nice weekend

Comment: why **select new { mt.MTypeID, mt.Name });** or not **select new Types { TypeID = mt.MTypeID, Name = mt.Name });**?